# Messaging app: spans adding on instead of creating new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

How can I align each span one after the other. As you see can my messages are grouped in purple and the other person's message are grouped in gray. They are not displaying sequentially. [image]

It seems that the spans keep adding on as per their css class. I'm not exactly sure the best way to tackle this problem. Please see my code below:

```
    <div class="chat-window">
      <%  messagesArray.forEach(function(sentMessage){  %>
      <%   if (sentMessage.message.length != 0){        %>

      <span class="chat-message"><%= sentMessage.message %></span>

      <%     }    %>
      <%    });   %>

      <%  messagesArray.forEach(function(otherMessage){   %>
      <%   if (otherMessage.otherMessage.length != 0){    %>

      <span class="chat-message-other"><%= otherMessage.otherMessage %></span>

      <%     }  %>
      <%    }); %>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.chat-window{
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.chat-message{
  color: white;
  background-color: #3b2593;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.chat-message-other{
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate two times over the same dataset. Displaying the sent messages the first time and the receives messages the second time.

You should only iterate once to reflect the order of messages accordingly:

```
<div class="chat-window">
  <%  messagesArray.forEach(function(sentMessage){  %>
  <%   if (sentMessage.message.length != 0){        %>
            <span class="chat-message"><%= sentMessage.message %></span>
  <%     }    %>
  <%   if (otherMessage.otherMessage.length != 0){    %>
            <span class="chat-message-other"><%= otherMessage.otherMessage %></span>
  <%     }  %>
  <%    }); %>
</div>
```